# Running bat file as administrator in pssesion

Tags: powershell, batch-file, administration

While using JEA, I created a configuration file that allow to specific user to connect as virtual account and to run specific bat file (start-process) with the the flag `-verb` that get parameter `'runAs'` to run the bat as Administrator.

The problem is that when the powershell run the bat the credential pop up and ask for a credential for an administrator on the current computer.
How can I let the virtual user run the bat as administrator without inserting a credential of a local administrator?

Answer (score 0):

Virtual accounts by definition are already local admins on the box, so you don't need to specify -verb runAs.

Please note that if you need to access anything on the network then that temporary virtual local admin will run under the computer account context and it's probably a better option to use a gMSA (group managed service account) so you can grant explicit privileges to that service account instead to the computer account.

You can find more on this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/jea/security-considerations)